# How to get the specific rows of the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, between

I am using Oracle database and I have a table that have 1.9 billion rows of records. I want to get the rows of records ranging from 100,000,001 to 200,000,000. Can someone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the SQL you have written so far? And perhaps include the structure for the table in question?

Comment: What are 100,000,001 to 200,000,000? Are these ID column values?

Comment: http://psoug.org/definition/ROWNUM.htm

Comment: ya what are 100,000,001 to 200,000,000?your are saying simply number of rows

Answer (score 2):

generally speaking you want a pagination query , which would be of the format:

```
select t.*
   from (select t.*, rownum rn
           from (select t.yourfields
                   from yourtab t
                  order by t.something)
          where rownum <= end_rownum
        ) t
  where rn >= offset;
```

or

```
select *
  from (select t.yourfields, row_number() over (order by t.something) rn
          from yourtab t)
 where rn between start_rownum and end_rownum;
```

Comment: Why do you want double select here? Single select with rownum in selection should also work.

Comment: @Indoknight: You mean, the way it is in your answer?

Comment: @Indoknight - because that's how `rownum` works; it's a question of when a value is assigned to the pseudocolumn. [See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) for more. Particularly the line 'Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false' and the paragraph following that example.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean those ranges are `rownum` then here is simple the query

```
select * from (select e.*,rownum test from hr.employees e) where test>5 and test <50;
```

Comment: This is the situation. I am migrating a table from Oracle database to Sybase IQ using the Sybase ETL. The table has a 1.9 Billion records and I want to chop the data by batch. For example, my batching would be: 1 to 100, 000, 000 then 100, 000, 001 to 200, 000, 000 then 200, 000, 001 to 300, 000, 000 etc. I know a little about Oracle so I need help on how I can batch the data?